# How to get cookie value from response using angular

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I currently work on a project using .Net Core 3.1 for server and angular for the client.

I`m storing my values in a session using .net core session, now when I send a post request using postman I can see the key the response sent me back under Cookies tab (the name is .AspNetCore.Session), also when I send the request from my client I see in the network tab the desirable response under Response Headers but when I try to return it as an Observable it returns as null. [image]

Now my question is how can I access that set-cookie from the client? I tried some approaches and none was good.

my current startup.cs ConfigureServices:

```
        {

            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
            services.AddCors();
        
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
            });
            
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped<IFavoriteRepository, FavoriteRepository>();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1800);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

        }
```

session methods

```
public void AddRepo(Repository repo)
        {

            var repository = new Repository() { RepoName = repo.RepoName, AvatarUrl = repo.AvatarUrl };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(repository);
             _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("SessionUser", json);
            
        }

        public Repository GetRepo()
        {
             var sessionUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Repository>(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionUser"));
            return sessionUser;
        }
```

controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddFavorite(Repository repo)
        {
            _repo.AddRepo(repo);
            return Ok();
        }
```

angular service

```
saveRepo(repo: Repository) {

    return this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + "Repositories", repo ,{ observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          return response.headers;
        })).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Making the cookie `httpOnly` prevents the script from accessing it. Try deleting this line

```
options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
```

(or altering it to ...`= false;`).

Comment: I tried with no success, I tried both ways delete and change to false ..